# Filling a custom-drawn shape in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics

I'm trying to fill an ellipse that I've made, but although I can get it to draw the outline, I can't get it to fill it. I've looked at a bunch of resources, including http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-shape-fill/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes, but following the advice there didn't fix the problem. I've tried to account for other errors - like spelling mistakes, errors with passing parameters, or errors with my ellipse-drawing method, but they all work independently just fine. I can draw the outline of ellipse. I can pass the context to a function. I can fill a non-ellipse. But I can't get my ellipse to fill. Here is what the code looks like:

```
main();

function main(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('landscape');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // var mySky = new sky(0, 0);
    // mySky.render(context);
    var myLake = new lake(400, 500, context);
    myLake.render(context);
    var ctx = context;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(75,50);
    ctx.lineTo(100,75);
    ctx.lineTo(100,25);
    ctx.fill();
}

function lake(x, y, context){

    this.context = context;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    var width = this.context.canvas.width/2;
    var height = this.context.canvas.height/4;
    var a = width/2;
    var b = height/2;
    var phi = Math.PI/2;

    this.render = function(context){
        var inc = (2*Math.PI)/200;
        var end = 200*inc;
        var oldX = oldY = newX = newY = 0;
        var x_0 = xcoord(0);
        var y_0 = ycoord(0);
        console.log("" + x_0 + ", " + y_0);
        var i = 0;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x_0, y_0);
        while(i < end){
            i += inc;
            newX = xcoord(i);
            newY = ycoord(i);
            context.lineTo(newX, newY);
            context.moveTo(newX, newY);
            console.log("" + newX + ", " + newY);
        }
        context.lineTo(x_0, y_0); // close up the ellipse
        context.moveTo(x_0, y_0);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStyle = '#6EB1F5';
        context.fill();
    }

    function xcoord(t){
        return x + a*Math.cos(t)*Math.sin(phi) + b*Math.sin(t)*Math.cos(phi);
    }

    function ycoord(t){
        return y + a*Math.cos(t)*Math.cos(phi) - b*Math.sin(t)*Math.sin(phi);
    }
```

Am I using the fill() function correctly? Is it because my ellipse isn't closed up properly? Please don't give me too much information if possible - I'd like to do it on my own, I just can't figure out what's wrong and I've spent nearly 3 hours trying to figure this out now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try by removing the `moveTo` the following places:

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(x_0, y_0); /// keep this
while(i < end){
    i += inc;
    newX = xcoord(i);
    newY = ycoord(i);
    context.lineTo(newX, newY);
    ///context.moveTo(newX, newY);  /// remove this
    console.log("" + newX + ", " + newY);
}
///context.lineTo(x_0, y_0); /// not needed as closePath will close it
///context.moveTo(x_0, y_0); /// remove this
context.closePath();
```

As you are using `moveTo` for each new coordinates you will create sub-paths consisting of only a single line which can't be filled. You want to create a continuous line which are closed at the end forming a closed polygon.

Besides from that, you are using `fill()` correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I guess I didn't understand how moveTo() and lineTo() worked together. And of course, now that I look at the tutorials, I see that they each only used moveTo() once. Blargh...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking, there are easier and cheaper ways of drawing an ellipse.

Something like the following:

```
function ellipse(context, x, y, a, b, theta) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.save();
    /* translate to avoid having our x and y values scaled */
    context.translate(x, y); 
    /* we can even do some rotation. (rotate before stretching!) */
    context.rotate(theta);
    /* now stretch the axes */
    context.scale(a, b);
    /* circle of radius 1, centred at the origin */
    context.arc(0, 0, 1, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    /* undo transformations */
    context.restore();
    context.closePath();
}
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hnttM/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function ellipse(context, x, y, a, b, theta) {
context.beginPath();
context.save();
/* translate to avoid having our x and y values scaled */
context.translate(x, y);
    context.scale(Math.random() * 1 ,Math.random() * 1);

/* we can even do some rotation. (rotate before stretching!) */
context.rotate(theta);
/* now stretch the axes */
context.scale(a, b);
/* circle of radius 1, centred at the origin */
context.arc(0, 0, 1, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
/* undo transformations */
context.restore();
context.closePath();};

setInterval(function(){abc()}, 100);
var c = document.getElementById("c");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function abc()
{
c.width = c.width;
for (var i=0; i < 20; i++) {
ellipse(ctx, i*50+25, 100, 20, 30, Math.random() * 10 - 5);
if (i % 3)
    ctx.fill();
else
    ctx.stroke();
};
};
```